# How can I modify the statusbar only when the active tab is of a certain file type

Tags: visual-studio-code, statusbar

I have created an extension for VSC that adds some statusbar buttons when a file of type JS/TS is opened. But I would rather only show the buttons if the active tab is JS/TS. Currently if I open a markdown file and a JS file the status bar buttons are added even when the MD file is the active tab.

Is there some kind of event that gets called when users swap tabs that I could use to show/hide my buttons.

Here is my repo:

https://github.com/sketchbuch/vsc_quokka_statusbar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Changing active text editor event

```js
vscode.window.onDidChangeActiveTextEditor(editor => {
    if (!editor) {
        // hide
        return;
    }
    if (editor.document.languageId === 'javascript' || editor.document.languageId === 'typescript') {
        // show
    } else {
        // hide
    }
});
```

---

If you want to consider all visible editors (split/grid):

```js
vscode.window.onDidChangeVisibleTextEditors(editors => {
    if (editors.some(editor => {
        return editor.document.languageId === 'javascript' || editor.document.languageId === 'typescript';
    })) {
        // show
    } else {
        // hide
    }
});
```